# What is the specific nuance of "ask against"?

Tags: word-usage

English is not my native tongue. I am helping another non-native to translate as precisely as possible a sentence that comes from an astrological reading:

> indicating that the **question is asked against an awareness** that the
>   mother has recently been afflicted by illness

I'd interpret *against* in this case to mean *in presence of*; that is, the person asking is aware of the illness and is probably influenced by this knowledge in posing his/her questions to the astrologer.

Is this correct? When would you use *ask against*, and what precisely is it used to communicate?

Comment: "*ask against*" is not a quite set phrase or idiom. *Against* here seems to be used in the sense of *in the face of*, i.e., "the question is asked, **knowing very well that** the mother has recently been afflicted by illness" (*Against an awareness*: in spite of knowing that)

Comment: Is the question being asked *because* we are aware of the recent illness or *in spite of* our awareness?

Comment: Please provide the full sentence.

Comment: The "full sentence" is the quoted part of the original question. Also, it was posted 11 years ago so you'll understand that I cannot provide more context at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Against](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/against)* here is used in the sense of *before the background of*. This can refer to physical objects or metaphorically otherwise.

Comment: "before the background of"? You mean "against the background of" maybe.

Comment: "before the background of" is a quote from Merriam-Webster. It would hardly make sense to define "against" using the word "against".